# How to populate struts2 combo with string array

Tags: combobox, struts2

statesList is ArrayList that contains String object.

```
String[] states = new String[2];
states[0] = "CA";
states[1] = "California";
statesList.add(states);

//---

<s:select list="statesList"  headerKey="" headerValue="Select State"  name="state" listKey="?" listValue="?" />
```

What to mention in listKey and listValue??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `statesList` is `ArrayList` that contains `String[]` object, instead of `String`.

With this said you can change your code to:

```
Map<String,String> statesList= new HashMap()<String,String>;
statesList.put("CA","California");

<s:select list="statesList" headerKey="" headerValue="Select State"  name="state" listKey="key" listValue="value" />
```